# Angular view not updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I modify $scope after a $timeout, my view doesn't get rendered properly.  I don't understand why.  It works if I don't do the $timeout first.

http://plnkr.co/edit/oGuPgt7VaYKgPFh00lDV?p=preview

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script>

angular.module('treeApp', [])

.controller('TreeController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {

  // This works
  // $scope.nodes = {
  //   1:{node_id:1, text:'foo text', parent_id:null, child_ids:[2,3]},
  //   2:{node_id:2, text:'bar text', parent_id:1, child_ids:[]},
  //   3:{node_id:3, text:'abc text', parent_id:1, child_ids:[]}
  // }
  // $scope.top_ids = [1]

  // This doesn't work
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.nodes = {
      1:{node_id:1, text:'foo text', parent_id:null, child_ids:[2,3]},
      2:{node_id:2, text:'bar text', parent_id:1, child_ids:[]},
      3:{node_id:3, text:'red text', parent_id:1, child_ids:[]}
    }
    $scope.top_ids = [1]
  }, 1000)
}])

</script>


<div ng-app="treeApp">

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="node.html">
    <li node_id="{{node_id}}" ng-repeat="node_id in node_ids" ui-tree-node
        ng-init="node = nodes[node_id]">
      {{node.text}}
      <ol ng-include="'node.html'" ng-init="node_ids = node.child_ids"></ol>
    </li>
  </script>

  <div ng-controller="TreeController">
    <ol ng-include="'node.html'" ng-init="node_ids = top_ids"></ol>
    <pre>{{top_ids | json}}</pre>
    <pre>{{nodes | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try assigning your $scope to a variable and use that variable inside the timeout or maybe provide a fiddle

Comment: I tried assigning $scope to a variable but it didn't fix the problem.  I did provide a plunkr (see the link right above the code).

Comment: Never use `ng-init` unless you need to save outer index in nested `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ol ng-include="'node.html'" ng-init="node_ids = top_ids"></ol>
```

You initialize `node_ids` with `top_ids`. It's a one-time assignment, not a binding. When you use `$timeout` the value of `top_ids` is `undefined` at the point of the assignment.

The easiest solution is to rename `$scope.top_ids` to `$scope.node_ids` and get rid of `ng-init`.

Answer (score 0):

use `$scope.$apply();` like below

```
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.nodes = {
      1:{node_id:1, text:'foo text', parent_id:null, child_ids:[2,3]},
      2:{node_id:2, text:'bar text', parent_id:1, child_ids:[]},
      3:{node_id:3, text:'abc text', parent_id:1, child_ids:[]}
    }
    $scope.top_ids = [1];
    $scope.$apply();
  }, 1000)
```

or you can wrap model changes like below,

```
$timeout(function() {    
    $scope.$apply(function () {
         $scope.nodes = {
                1:{node_id:1, text:'foo text', parent_id:null, child_ids:[2,3]},
                2:{node_id:2, text:'bar text', parent_id:1, child_ids:[]},
                3:{node_id:3, text:'abc text', parent_id:1, child_ids:[]}
         }
         $scope.top_ids = [1];
    });
}, 1000)
```

here is a good [demo](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest),

Here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8EwqqHNEaLv9dPm10rKk?p=preview)

**if you change any model outside of the Angular context, then you need to inform Angular of the changes by calling $apply() manually..... For example, if you use JavaScript’s setTimeout() function to update a scope model, Angular has no way of knowing what you might change. In this case it’s your responsibility to call $apply() manually**

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.  I'm pretty sure $timeout automatically calls $apply.

Comment: That plunkr is not working.  There is supposed to be a tree rendered above the raw json.  Uncomment the commented code in order to see it.